# How to emit momentjs dates in correct format

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I am trying to format my data to send it to parent component but it seem like it is not reactive

```
      if(this.selectedDate !== '' && this.selectedMonth !== '' && this.selectedDate !== '' ){
    this.$emit("emit-data",  this.selectedYr+"-"+moment().set(this.selectedDate) .format("DD")+"- "+moment().set(this.selectedMonth).format("MM"))
  }
```

It won't send the selected drop-down but default ones which were pre-selected on page load. But If I take off `moment()` format from the data being sent, it sent correct values but I still need that format the data be in e.g `YYYY-DD-MM`

Is there any way to do this is computed using setters and getters before emitting? I am not sure how but If there is a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely use a reactive computed getter for this. Here is an example:

```html
<div id="app">
  <parent-component />
</div>
```

```js
const parentComponent = Vue.component('parent-component', {
  data () {
    return {
      formattedDate: null
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>You have selected: {{ formattedDate || "nothing yet" }}.</p>

      <child-component
        @emit-data="(payload) => formattedDate = payload"
      />
    </div>
  `
})

const childComponent = Vue.component('child-component', {
  data () {
    return {
      selectedDate: null,
      selectedMonth: null,
      selectedYear: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formattedDate () {
      if (![this.selectedDate, this.selectedMonth, this.selectedYear].every((el) => el)) return null
      
      return moment({
        day: this.selectedDate,
        // Months in Moment.js are 0-indexed!
        month: this.selectedMonth - 1,
        year: this.selectedYear
      }).format("YYYY-DD-MM")
    }
  },
  watch: {
    formattedDate (newVal) {
      this.$emit("emit-data", newVal)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <input v-model="selectedDate" type="number" placeholder="Day" min="1" max="31" step="1">
      <input v-model="selectedMonth" type="number" placeholder="Month" min="1" max="12" step="1">
      <input v-model="selectedYear" type="number" placeholder="Year" min="1900" max="2100" step="1">
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

You can run the above interactively on https://jsfiddle.net/46vuLcy0/.

Comment: thnx, Problem is that I have dropdown which has months in Alphanumeric format which I need to convert in to numeric format in the emit

Comment: What is an _alphanumeric format_ in this context? I don't think we will be able to help you further unless you provide the full code you are working with.

Comment: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-moment-to-live-in-66yvf?file=/src/App.vue) you with a example. so I want the emitted data month to be formatted as in 07 e.g for july

Comment: There you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-moment-to-live-in-q6hg8?file=/src/App.vue. Observe the console to see when the event gets emitted and with what payload.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.$emit('emit-data', moment(new Date(this.selectedMonth + "-" + this.selectedDate + "-" + this.selectedYr)).format(YYYY-DD-MM))
```

You can also see these [examples](https://codepen.io/bassfiddle/pen/lrLwy)

## UPDATE

In the above code, your data is processed in to `moment` date. The result of this can be formatted in to your desired format.

**Example**

If you want the date to be `15-JUL-2020`, you can have

```
moment(/* your date */).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

Your can be directly provided to moment like

```
this.$emit("emit-data", moment(this.selectedYr + "-" + this.selectedDate + "-" + this.selectedMonth).format("YYYY-DD-MM"))
```

The code will result something like `2020-15-07` based on the format.

Comment: thanks, I did some experiment and watcher changed the data (see my updated question) it but with ur example and mine. what is the difference, what does `newDate()` does? I thought `moment()` gives u time object

Comment: `new Date()` will convert your string date format to UTC format which moment will recognize.

Comment: The code format is wrong.  `this.$emit(...).format is not a function`

Comment: @Nofel Updated the snippet

Comment: thanks, its great. few things which I didn't understand. 1. why wasn't my code reactive e.g why won't it emit selected dropdown and emit today's date even after selection 2. what is reason for computed as method and computed code look too similar?

Comment: @Nofel Could you please a bit elaborative on whats the actual need? I found your sandbox months not populated based on the selected year.

Comment: It is what I needed, I m trying to understand that when I just `$emit('...', `${this.selectedYr}-${this.selectedMonth}-${this.selectedDate}`)` it would emit today's date so what is different between that and your code?